# find coordinates of point 2 on perimeter of circle at angle P from point 1 on perimeter, not from centre

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

A circle has known radius r and centre coordinates XcYc.
There is an inscribed square with known corner point 1, with coordinates X1Y1.

Problem to solve:

Calculate the unknown coordinates X2Y2 of a new point 2 on the circumference of the same circle, which lies at new angle P degrees. P degrees is measured clockwise from the side of the inscribed square. Please see the attached diagram link below.

Any help in generating a formula to calculate X2 Y2 from the other known variables  r, XcYc, X1Y1,P, would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image: link to pictorial of problem to be solved]

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do it for you, but I will give a big hint and not flag the problem. I would first solve the problem with the square drawn horiz and vertical and X1,Y1 as the origin. Then the equation for the circle is an expression of Xc,Yc,r. Actually Xc,Yc is r away from X1,Y1 now too, and Xc=Yc. After solving, either try to generalize or translate coordinates. It seems over-specified, but actually it’s not because you will need those to know the angle of the square from vertical.

Let me know if have questions after trying.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Ignore three blue sides of square not contacting yellow angle arms. Look for an isosceles triangle.

EDIT1:

Inside given square side $a$ the equal angles of an isosceles triangle are

$$( p- 45^{\circ}) $$ opposite to equal sides as radii $ a/\sqrt 2. $

Comment: yes that would be easy if we knew the length of the yellow line - but we don't!

Comment: Please see hint edited

Answer (score 0):

Hint: solve it with the angle at the center of the circle.

[image]